# Use the data table returned in a call back as a dataframe in another callback in Plolty Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I want to use a data table which is made after some data manipulation in the original data frame. Now, I want to use that modified data table as a data frame in a another callback. I know about dcc.Store, but I don't really know how it stores the data from a callback. The code I have written is as follows:

```
def update_graph(n):

if n is None:
    return dash.no_update

else:
    
    check_df2 =df[df['Year'] == 2020]

    df_num = check_df2.select_dtypes(include='number')  #Select dataframe without strings

    hello= norm_df(df_num)   #For normalization of the data, only numbers

    check_df2[hello.columns] = hello   #Again the complete dataframe.



    return  html.Div([

        html.Div([
        dash_table.DataTable(
        data=check_df2.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in check_df2.columns],
        page_size=5)

        ]),
```

I want to use the new data frame check_df2 in another callback for visualization. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the dash wrapper for your `update_graph(n)` function.
But if it's in the style of

```
@app.callback(Output('htmlDiv_variable', 'output_element'),
              [Input('n_variable', 'input_trigger')])
def update_graph(n):
.
.
.
return html.Div(...)
```

what you can do is add an initially empty html.Div element to your UI where you can store your data for later use.

html.Div(id='container_Div', style={'display':'none'})

```
@app.callback([Output('htmlDiv_variable', 'children')
               Output('container_Div', 'children')],
              [Input('n_variable', 'input_trigger')])
def update_graph(n):
.
.
.
return html.Div(...), check_df2
```

This is how it was done before the Store component was introduced. However using dcc.Store would just work analogous. You add a dcc.Store object to your UI and the fill use it as an additional ouput in one function and it can be then used as an input in another function